# Vugen - Not able to launch IE in Windows 2012 Server R2

Tags: internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012, vugen

We have installed VUgen12.53 in Windows 2012 Server R2. WHen we are trying to record, we get an exception that, ' You need to close all Internet Explorer Browsers' After clicking  'OK' another popup appears ' Please close IE and all instances manually'

There are no IE instances opened and I have checked the Running process, even there I can't see any process related to IE. THis issue is occurring for every Browser (CHrome / Firefox) which are present in that Server.

Any Suggestions on how we can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

this issue can happen when there are other users that running one of the browsers.

try to make sure that there are no other users with those process.